# INSERT multidimensional array to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array

Is there any hack when inserting multidimensional array to postgres?
I would like to insert smth like

```
INSERT INTO Timesheet (day, startTime, endTime, idSchedule)
VALUES(unnest(array['TUE', 'FRI']),
       unnest(array[['10:00', '02:00'], ['10:00']]),
       unnest(array[['14:00', '23:00'], ['14:00']]), 1);
```

Or in detail

```
INSERT INTO Timesheet (day, startTime, endTime, idSchedule)
VALUES('TUE', '10:00', '14:00', 1),
      ('TUE', '02:00', '23:00', 1),
      ('FRI', '10:00', '14:00', 1);
```

Query fails with

```
ERROR: multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
```

Maybe there are any solutions?

Comment: What data type is `starttime` Do you really store an array in that column? Are you trying to insert two rows? One for TUE, one for FRI? Why can't you use `values ('TUE, array[...], '10:00', 1), ('FRI', array[...], '14:00', 1)`?

Comment: No, I need to unnest my array twice - e.g. for Tuesday I have to insert startTime=10:00 and startTime=02:00

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. If you need multiple rows, then why don't you use a `values` clause that specifies multiple rows? `array[['10:00', '02:00'], ['10:00']` is simply an invalid array as the first element is a two dimensional array and the second is a one dimensional array, you will have to change that to `array[['10:00', '02:00'], ['10:00', '10:00']]` if you want to keep that strange approach

Comment: array[['10:00', '02:00'], ['10:00', '10:00']] is not what I want - for FRI there is only one startTime='10:00'. I have to insert two rows for TUE and one for FRI. In what way you suggest me using VALUES clause? Will you please explain?

Comment: Something like `VALUES
  ('TUE', '10:00', '10:00', 1),
  ('TUE', '02:00', '10:00', 1),
  ('FRI', '14:00', '14:00', 1)
` I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I added explanation to the question

Comment: @Jane What is the actual query input, where are you getting data in this weird multidimensional-array-like format from?

Comment: Input format is an array of elements with the unique time, I am trying to implement insertion in one row... The weird array I get after processing with python. In what way I am to rewrite query in case there are not equal time-intervals for the days?

Comment: @Jane You might want to post that python code so that we can help with it specifically. But the format in my answer should work for your use case - just repeat the respective day as often as there are intervals for it.

Comment: I was hoping to accomplish something similar with sql-template strings. I was hoping to find I could pass a two-dimensional array to be used with placeholder that would auto-magically go from [[1, 'X', 'Y'][2, 'V', 'Z']] to a bunch of (1, 'X', 'Y'), (1, 'V', 'Z') insert-compatible value sets. `insert into my_table (id, value1, value2) values $1, [myTwoDArray]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
INSERT INTO Timesheet (day, startTime, endTime, idSchedule)
VALUES(unnest(array['TUE', 'TUE', 'FRI']),
       unnest(array['10:00', '02:00', '10:00']),
       unnest(array['14:00', '23:00', '14:00']), 1);
```

Comment: thank you for the idea! it works great. I overwrote my Python script so there are no any nested arrays. I imagined there is a way to flatten nested arrays when inserting rows to Postgres. I found it is possible only when they are equal. So your solution is only possible in my case

Comment: There surely is some way to do that in Postgres as well (e.g. by using JSON nested arrays, which are not "multidimensional arrays" of the same length), but it's probably much easier to do the flattening in the Python script.